# How can I detect if all JSON fields are being parsed?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON annotations to parse JSON fields from a restful service into a DTO.  I wanted to write a test which would detect if there where any fields in JSONObject that are not yet being parsed into the Java DTO object that has the annotations.  If on the server they add ten fields I will have no way of knowing this?  Is there any way to test dynamically if all fields are being parsed into the Java object?

To put this another way, could I get the names of all the DTO fields (including annotation info), and compare that all the fields on the JSON object.  So I am trying to compare DTO to JSONObject to see if I have covered everything.

Answer (score 1):

Gson itself doesn't have anything like this. "Extra" fields in Java or the JSON are silently ignored. Fields present in Java but not in JSON are set to `null`

The only way you could so this is via reflection, either during Gson's deserialization with a custom deserializer or by parsing the JSON to a `JsonObject` using Gson's `JsonParser` class and doing your test.

You'd need to get all the field names from the `JsonObject` via  `entrySet()`, all the field names from the Java class using `Class.getDeclaredFields()` and compare the two sets to find which ones are not present in both.

Comment: Ok. I think I will try this.  Will getDeclaredFields() also return the annotation information?  eg. GSON's @SerializedName("theNameInJSON")
                              public String theName;

Comment: Yes - if you look at the reflection API,`Field` encapsulates everything about the field and has `getDeclaredAnnotations()`